# Ubuntu 13.04 Boot stuck at the changing Orange & White Dots. How can I get it to work?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I had done a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.04 a few days ago as a dual boot with Windows. Last night since the PC was behaving a bit sluggish I tried to restart Ubuntu. The bootup reached the GRUB loader and stopped because there was no 10 seconds countdown.

I used an Ubuntu 13.04 LiveUSB and got access of root & recovered my files. I repaired the boot-loader with this LiveUSB.

Now the PC boots Windows & even has the 10 seconds countdown. However, when booting into Ubuntu 13.04 the boot gets stuck at the moving Orange & White Dots. These Orange dots turn to white & white to Orange endlessly. It does not boot further. I need to get to the Desktop to use the computer. Please help. Thanks.

P.S. I read similar questions but do not have any problems with the graphics card, which is an integrated Intel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per instructions given by Hamish I booted into the recovery mode from the GRUB loader, and then selected "Repair broken Packages".

I also ran fsck twice. It is a long message which in part said "Inode that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found". It also stated in part "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck manually ... status 4" & "mountall: Filesystem has errors:/"

I got an option which I don't completely recollect that said it could repair the errors. I accepted it & it solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Not a solution as such:
If you press the 'Esc' key during the Ubuntu boot process it should show you what is going on in the background and might give you a hint where the boot process is getting stuck.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you Steve for your response. I got a solution to this problem thanks to Hamish. The details are here: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/228830/+index